# How do we exclude multiple pages (like opposite of is_page)

Tags: pages, woocommerce-offtopic

### Scenario

I have a following customized format for the website with Woocommerce.

1. **`<?php if(is_shop()) {?>`** There are certain css styles, JS options used for this particular page
2. **`<?php } if(is_front_page()) { ?>`** Same as above with different css animations used or certain classes when on home page of the site

### Question

Now, I want to use some specific jQuery options such as .Delay(), Hide(), & Show() on `pages other than Shop & Home page`

However, If I simply add the jQuery outside the options `1` & `2` mentioned above .. this gets applied to entire website -- overriding options specified for `is_shop`

I think if we can exclude pages then I can exclude these 2 pages above. Writing `is_page (array)` would be too tedious for hundreds of pages.

How can we exclude certain WP pages (in my case only 2)? Or should I re-format the page using `if else` & will it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The opposite of `is_page()` will be `! is_page()`. In php the `!` is used as negative, so `! is_page( 42 )` will means something like

> if we are not on page ID 42, do something, in other words exclude page ID 42

Comment: Thanks so much Pieter. That worked! Probably, I was under a different impression about using `!` . I'm answering too. 

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Pieter, that solved the issue. I'm writing below some details just in case someone comes here in future.

As stated by Pieter in answer above, using `!is_page` is for excluding the page in opposite of using `is_page` for including functions for that page.

In my case, I noticed two things.

1. **`<?php if(!is_shop() && (!is_front_page()))  {?>`** I used the code needed everywhere else other than these 2 pages. Works great
2. All the jQuery options needs to be common in all cases to work. We cannot ignore it in any of the cases. Which means, I had to mention jQuery options in all three cases to make it work as desired.

> In my example: I had `is_shop()`, `is_front_page()` & `!is_shop()`
>   where each of them needed this `jQuery("#primary").delay($value)` for
>   it to work as desired on all pages.

Thanks all.

Comment: Thanks for sharing exactly what you did, and thanks for keeping this site constructive. +1